# Light curve analysis: how to estimate temperatures of Binary star system

Tags: astronomy, astrophysics, models

I'm stuck at a binary star system lightcurve analysis.

I have to set initial values for the bodies temperatures and then improve their accuracy by fitting. I know that the system type is WUMa.

How can I estimate $T_{eff}$ values? Are there any empyrical relations in astrophysics literature?

I already have period value and estimations for $M_1, M_2, R_1, R_2$ (Gazeas & Stepien, 2008) and distance.

Comment: You haven't given enough information to answer the question. In general you cannot get absolute temperatures from a light curve unless you know the distance. Other than that you can get a temperature ratio.

Comment: @RobJeffries you're right. In fact I also have an estimation for distance. Can you give some hints about how to proceed?

Answer (score 1):

From a lightcurve all you can get is a temperature ratio.

The relative contribution to the light curves are $R_{1}^2 T_{1}^4/R_{2}^2 T_{2}^4$. The relative surface brightnesses are $(T_1/T_2)^4$.

At primary eclipse minimum, some area of the primary is eclipsed by the secondary. At secondary minimum, the same area of the secondary is eclipsed by the primary. The ratio of fluxes at these points therefore gives $T_{2}^4/T_{1}^4$ and hence the temperature ratio.

Now you can express the total luminosity as
$$ L = 4\pi \sigma R_{1}^2 T_{1}^2\left(1 + \frac{R_{2}^{2}T_{2}^4}{R_{1}^2 T_{1}^{4}}\right)$$

But you can now evaluate the bracket, and if you know what the bolometric flux, $f$ from the binary (out of eclipse), then if the distance is $d$, the left hand side can be replaced by $L =4\pi d^2 f$. You then rearrange to get $T_1$ and hence everything is determined.

Of course the above simplified discussion ignores limb darkening and assumes the stars are black bodies.

Comment: A lot of thanks, I'm not an astrophysics student, so I have some doubts... If I want to calculate the flux at the minima, is it correct the formula $F_v=10^(-0.4 (V_{mag}-V_{min}))$ where $V_{mag}$ is the apparent magnitude at the minima and $V_{min}$ is the minimum value of the magnitude? And then How can I obtain the bolometric flux? A lot of thanks for your help

Comment: @sunrise Actually, that is a flux ratio. Bolometric fluxes are related to bolometric magnitudes. These are found from visual magnitudes using bolometric corrections.

Comment: What quantity are you referring to with "flux ratio"? Could you give me some formula or references to calculate bolometric flux? I have found this paper http://articles.adsabs.harvard.edu/cgi-bin/nph-iarticle_query?1996ApJ...469..355F&amp;data_type=PDF_HIGH&amp;whole_paper=YES&amp;type=PRINTER&amp;filetype=.pdf but I haven't understood in which way I can use it...

Comment: @sunrise A magnitude difference is a flux ratio. $v_1 - v_2 = -2.5\log_{10} (f_1/f_2)$.  Bolometric magnitude $m_{bol} = v + BC$, where $BC$ is the bolometric correction. An *absolute* bolometric magnitude (for which you need the distance) corresponds to a total bolometric flux of $3\times10^{28}$ W. All this is on the wikipedia page on bolometric correction.